# Control iPhone app getting updated when connected to old webservices

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, xamarin.ios, updates

We are looking to develop an iPhone App communicating to webservices that is hosted internally at the customer site. Note that this is our first iPhone native App and using monotouch to do the job.

We will be maintaining the code and release updates periodically. However, the users needs to update only the version required based on thier local webservices and backend processes. For example, if the user is still using the version 1 webservice don't need to update the App at all, where as the users with version 2 needs to update to the matching App and so on.

We want to control the updating process or at least find a solution where if the user updates to the latest App, it won't come up with an error because the connected webservice is out of date.

We were thinking of the following processes, but nothing seems to be solving the issue.

1) Leave the app on the appstore but control the update processes somehow based on the webservices version. So when a user try to update, it will not update unless the required webservices is available. (Annoying part on this is users may be prompt that there is an update available even though those are irrelavent for them.)

2) Control the update outside the AppStore. Something similar to In-house development.

3) Stop the updating process entirely from the client, and only trigger the updates from the webservices end.

```
i.e Inform the client that it needs to update when the webservices updated, and the client will run the update process at that point.

However, it could be tricky, if the customer's updated to the webservices version that is not the latest.
```

Answer (score 0):

1) There is no way to do what you want to do with Apple's AppStore, either an app can be updated or it can not, you can't add additional conditions that requires running code on the device itself.

2) That leaves in-house enterprise deployment - but this is restricted to deploying to your own company, you can't deploy to different clients this way.

3) You can't stop updates from your app, since you can't run code when an app is updated.

There is a 4), but it requires more work on your end:

4) Have your app support support older webservices, either through some sort of configuration the user can set or it query the web service for its version and selects accordingly. This has the additional advantage that an update can be deployed to all the devices first, and once all the devices have been updated, update the web service.

Comment: lol @Rolf exactly my words... except for point 3:  a) users love updates + b) there _will_ be critical bugs

Answer (score 0):

I would propose a fourth option: dont control/limit updating :)

Ship an app that uses a Wrapper object to access the service and that object internally handles different versions of the webservice.

---

apart from that.

- 1) doesnt work (if I get what you're doing: trying to influence the appstore updating)
- 2) sounds doable, and if you dont care for the appstore, it works
- 3) why? users love updates :) + there will be critical bugs